Can I send a inspect element change to others via link?
I would like to share what I have changed with a inspect element to others. Can I embed the changes in a URL? Say I have a website I don't own I inspect element it myself to say xyz instead of abc. Can I send this changed view to another person via URL?
Thanks!
I tried to do some research and did not find anything.

The short answer is "no".  Your changes exist only in your browser's memory.
